# With FileField, opening file before inserting database

Tags: python, django

I have `models`, `serializer` and viewsets with `FileField`

```
class Drawing(SafeDeleteModel):
    drawing = f.FileField(upload_to='uploads/')

class DrawingSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    drawing = serializers.FileField()


class DrawingViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = m.Drawing.objects.all()
    serializer_class = s.DrawingSerializer
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)    
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            
        print("serializer request:",request.data['drawing']) # this is myfile.pdf
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        print("serializer seliarizer",serializer.data['drawing']) 
 # myfile_ccA3TjY.pdf
        try:
         doc = fitz.open(file_path) # open to check if it is correct pdf
        except;
         raise Exception("file is not valid pdf")
```

When uploading file,`request.data['drawing']` is `myfile.pdf`, `serializer.data['drawing']` is real name `myfile_ccA3TjY.pdf`. ( when there is the same name file)

So for opening file with `fitz`, I need to know the real name `myfile_ccA3TjY.pdf`.

I have to do `self.perform_create` to know the real file name, and it creates the row. However I want to cancel inserting to database when file is not valid pdf.

With this code database inserting is executed even file is not correct pdf.

Is there any way to open the file without calling `self.perform_create`?

Comment: *With this code database inserting is executed even file is not correct pdf.* - Because you're calling `self.perform_create()` method before validating it. Just put this method after `try: except` block it will not create if it's not valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/document.html#document) its possible to create file object from memory. So you can do something like this:

```
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)    
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            
        
        try:
         doc = fitz.open(“pdf”, request.data['drawing'])
         # or doc = fitz.open(“pdf”, request.data['drawing'].read())
        except;
         raise Exception("file is not valid pdf") 
        self.perform_create(serializer)
```

Comment: I use `read()` like this `f = request.data['drawing'].read()
            doc = fitz.open("pdf",f)` and it works.